# Ajax read JSON - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My report.php returns a json file. This is my javascript to try and read it:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'report.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data[0].name);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

JSON

```
{
    "report": {
        "type": "realtime",
        "elements": [{
            "id": "datetime",
            "name": "Date"
        }, {
            "id": "page",
            "name": "Page"
        }],
        "reportSuite": {
            "id": "myID",
            "name": "GD"
        },
        "period": "2018-08-31T08:31:26+0100\/2018-08-31T10:31:26+0100",
        "metrics": [{
            "id": "instances",
            "name": "Instances",
            "type": "number",
            "decimals": 0
        }],
        "data": [{
            "name": "2018-08-31T08:31:26+0100",
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 8,
            "day": 31,
            "hour": 8,
            "minute": 31,
            "breakdown": [{
                "name": ":A",
                "trend": "-91933.00",
                "counts": ["946801"]
            }, {
                "name": ":A Overview",
                "trend": "-97580.00",
                "counts": ["692229"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Successfull",
                "trend": "-39664.00",
                "counts": ["587378"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Trans",
                "trend": "-64227.00",
                "counts": ["440308"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Login",
                "trend": "-21233.00",
                "counts": ["367356"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Login - Enter Passcode",
                "trend": "-20456.00",
                "counts": ["334372"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Login - Complete",
                "trend": "-20724.00",
                "counts": ["321480"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Logiln - Complete",
                "trend": "-19448.00",
                "counts": ["291264"]
            }, {
                "name": "Li6",
                "trend": "-6278.00",
                "counts": ["100971"]
            }],
            "breakdownTotal": ["7118755"]
        }, {
            "name": "2018-08-31T09:31:26+0100",
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 8,
            "day": 31,
            "hour": 9,
            "minute": 31,
            "breakdown": [{
                "name": ":Accounts",
                "trend": "-91933.00",
                "counts": ["854868"]
            }, {
                "name": ":Overview",
                "trend": "-97580.00",
                "counts": ["594649"]
            }, {
                "name": "Li6",
                "trend": "-6278.00",
                "counts": ["94693"]
            }],
            "breakdownTotal": ["6613117"]
        }],
        "totals": ["13731872"],
        "version": "1.4.17.2"
    }
}
```

Instead of printing the json in console, it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.success (index.php:23)
    at c (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5)
```

Can anyone please help me understand why?

Comment: name of which element do you require?

Comment: `data` varable looks like an object to me, so I guess `data[0]` will be undefined?

Comment: your data is just an object use data.report.data[0].name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(data.report.data[0].breakdown[1].name);
```

Which will output `:A Overview`

Where 0 is the first element of your data array, and 1 is the second element of your breakdown array. Maybe you want to loop through the array with `.each()`?

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't shadow variables.
Rename your data to `result` (or something similar).
Secondly in your JSON you have to select the data type of the json.
Use `result.report.data[0].name`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JSON, I think you're missing accessing the "report" object, so what you want to get the name of the first data element is:

```
data.report.data[0].name
```

rather than just

```
data[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like

```
console.log(data.report.elements[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `data` is holding the entire response object. It is not an array. Why don't you try this way.

`data.report.elements[0].name`